# Rendering LuaTeX and tikzpicture plots in a Doxygen page

Tags: latex, doxygen

I am relatively new to documentation generation tools such as Doxygen. I am able to generate documentation for a hobbyist project, I've been working on. See [here](https://quantophile.github.io/ode_solvers/html/).

I have taken down some notes in LuaTeX (LaTeX) and these often include `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}` blocks for various scientific plots. Is there a way to include such a *.tex, verbatim in my Doxygen documentation, in such a way, that these tikzpicture plots are rendered on the fly?

It's rather cumbersome to manually save down each image and convert each *.tex file to the markdown format.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? In which output format do you want to incorporate these images? maybe have a look at the formula (!) possibilities and especially the part with `\f{`.

Comment: Regarding `LuaTex` maybe also have a look at the setting `LATEX_CMD_NAME` in the `Doxyfile`

Comment: @albert, I will try to see if I can get a working example. Is this something you've tried before?

Comment: By head I think I tried something with the `\f{` and tikz / tikzimage.